# comparing UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, comparison

Im working with multiple UITableViews in 1 class however i cant seperate them in my delegates. Why isnt this working:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    MenuHeader *header;
    if (tableView == myFirstTable) {
        header = [[MenuHeader alloc] initWithFrameAndTitel:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40) :@"Text for first table"];
    }
    else if (tableView == mySecondTable) {
        header = [[MenuHeader alloc] initWithFrameAndTitel:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40) :@"Text for second table"];
    }

    return header;
}
```

I put a breakpoint at the if statements but it never sets the header. Same happens in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

I declared my tableviews under @implementation:

```
UITableView *myFirstTable;
UITableView *mySecondTable;
UITableView *myThirdTable;
```

Then in the initialiser:

```
myFirstTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 180)];
myFirstTable.dataSource = self;
myFirstTable.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:myFirstTable];


...
```

EDIT

More code:

```
@implementation TableStuff

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

UITableView *myFirstTable;
UITableView *mySecondTalbe;
UITableView *myThirdTable;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code


        myFirstTable; = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 180)];;
        menuTable.dataSource = self;
        menuTable.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:menuTable];


        mySecondTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWi....
        more init...





    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What are the values of tableView, myFirstTable and mySecondTable if you set a breakpoint in the method?

Comment: Where do you initialize myFirstTable etc.? Are these instance variables? Do you use ARC?

Comment: Did you conform to the protocols in the header? Do you have "<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>" in your header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i just fixed this by adding a tag to the tableview and comparing tableview.tag with an integer. Still clueless why comparing two tableviews is not working.